# Flutter setState causes infinite loop

Tags: firebase, flutter, dart, firebase-realtime-database

I am newbie at Flutter, I want to fetch data once from Firebase but when I use foreach in setState, it gives infinite loop. I tried initState but I couldn't figure it out with Future.

Here is my code:

```
class _AnasayfaScreenState extends State<AnasayfaScreen> {
   final databaseRef = FirebaseDatabase.instance.reference();
   ActivityModel activity = ActivityModel();
   List<Map<dynamic, dynamic>> lists = [];
 }

Future getActivity() async {
return await databaseRef
    .child('activities')
    .limitToLast(3)
    .once()
    .then((DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
  setState(() {
    Map<dynamic, dynamic> values = dataSnapshot.value;
    lists.clear();
    values.forEach((key, values) {
      lists.add(values);
    });
  });
});
}
@override
Widget build(BuildContext context) {
getActivity();
return Scaffold(
    appBar: AppBar(
    // some stuff
  title: Text("Title: " +lists[index]["title"] +"\nDate: " + lists[index]["date"] +"\nN:  Number of people"+lists[index]["maxPeople"] + "\nActivity Owner: " +lists[index]["ownername"]),
```

Any help would be awesome for me, thanks.

Comment: Could you provide more code

Comment: @KęstutisRamulionis I added build widget and state class.

Comment: If we would speak on top level, what setState does is it calls build method. Inside of build method you are calling getActivity which calls setState, which calls build... and so on. Please take a look at FutureBuilder class, it should help you understand how Widget should be built when retrieving data. https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/FutureBuilder-class.html
In short, you should remove setState from your method, return Future and call getActivity inside FutureBuilder

Comment: The main issue is here `getActivity();` is being called just under the build method.

Comment: It works now after adding initState and removing getActivity from build, thanks a lot.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is a very basic example of what you can do:

```
class _AnasayfaScreenState extends State<AnasayfaScreen> {
   final databaseRef = FirebaseDatabase.instance.reference();
   ActivityModel activity = ActivityModel();
  bool isLoading = true;
  List<Map<dynamic, dynamic>> lists = [];
  
  @override
  void initState(){
    super.initState();
    getActivity();
  }
  
  Future getActivity() async {
    await databaseRef
    .child('activities')
    .limitToLast(3)
    .once()
    .then((DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
    Map<dynamic, dynamic> values = dataSnapshot.value;
    lists.clear();
    values.forEach((key, values) {
      lists.add(values);
        });
      });
    setState(() {
      isLoading = false;
    });
  }


  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      body: isLoading ? Container() // Add your widget and work here instead of Container
            : CircularProgressIndicator(),
    );  
  }
```